# Can Visual Studio use a 'Block Body' when using 'Generate Method', but still prefer 'Expression Body' otherwise? (VS2019)

Tags: editor, intellisense, visual-studio-2019

I use 'Generate Method' a lot (when typing a missing method call, Visual Studio offers to generate it), but when the options are set to prefer an Expression Body, it generates an Expression Body like this:

private void Blah() => throw new NotImplementedException();

I then have to convert it to a block body because most methods aren't one line.  Is there any way to get Visual Studio to generate block body methods but still suggest expression body methods?

Comment: Hi Kenzi, does my answer help you handle this issue?

Comment: Yes, thanks.  I think my question was somewhat misinformed - Given this setting, I expected Visual Studio to stop suggesting that I turn a one-line block body into an expression body.  I don't see how Visual Studio really suggests either way - but the code generation is more practical now, so I guess I'm all set.

Answer (score 4):

> I then have to convert it to a block body because most methods aren't
>   one line. Is there any way to get Visual Studio to generate block body
>   methods but still suggest expression body methods?

**Solution**

Please change this:

`Tools`-->`Options`-->`Text Editor`-->`C#`-->`Code Style`-->`Expression Preferences`-->

change **Preference** of `Use expression body for methods` to **Never**

[image]

Hope it could help you.